# PHP Email with attachement

Tags: php, email-attachments

Am facing a problem to sent a PHP email with an excel attachment. I can see the mail sent message, Mail is coming, but there is no attachment. I dint know the real problem. this is my code. I have put the User.xlsx file in my root directory. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

```
 $to = "dibeesh@amt.in";
    $subject="attachement";
    $mail_msg="message with attach";
    $filename="User.xlsx"; // Attachement file in root directory 
    $contentType="application/zip"; // Not sure about what to put here 
    $pathToFilename="./";
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
    $headers = "From: webmaster@mysite.com\r\nReply-To: ".$to;
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($pathToFilename)));
    ob_start();
    echo "
                --PHP-mixed-$random_hash
                Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"

                --PHP-alt-$random_hash
                Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
                Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

                $mail_msg

                --PHP-alt-$random_hash--

                --PHP-mixed-$random_hash
                Content-Type: $contentType; name=\"$filename\"
                Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
                Content-Disposition: attachment

                $attachment
                --PHP-mixed-$random_hash--
                ";

    $message = ob_get_clean();
    // $fh=fopen('log.txt','w');
    // fwrite($fh,$message);
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

Comment: If you want to figure out the issues with your manual mime construction, do so. Research the hundreds of other duplicates here. But don't ask others for debugging. Both PHPMailer and SwiftMailer allow for easy mail with attachment sending, without having to fiddle with that code you copied from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to debug my code, sorry for duplicate posting. It may help someone thanks

```
// Email to Client with attachement
                //define the receiver of the email
                $to = 'dibeesh@amt.in';
                //define the subject of the email
                $subject = 'Bayern3 Notification';
                $filename = "User.xlsx";
                //create a boundary string. It must be unique
                //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
                $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
                //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
                $headers = "From: lal@amt.in\r\nReply-To: dibeesh@amt.in";
                //add boundary string and mime type specification
                $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
                //read the atachment file contents into a string,
                //encode it with MIME base64,
                //and split it into smaller chunks
                $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename)));
                //define the body of the message.
                ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
                echo "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash
                        Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"

                        --PHP-alt-$random_hash
                        Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
                        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

                        --PHP-alt-$random_hash
                        Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
                        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

                           <h4>Hi,</h4>
                        <p><b>$userfullname</b> and his 10 friends qualified for <b>$venuename</b>. Please find the Excel sheet attached. You can download the detailed report form Bayern3 Admin Panel</p>

                        <h4>Regards,</h4>
                        <h4>Bayern3 Team</h4>
                        --PHP-alt-$random_hash--

                        --PHP-mixed-$random_hash
                        Content-Type: application/zip; name=$filename
                        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
                        Content-Disposition: attachment

                        $attachment
                        --PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";

                //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
                $message = ob_get_clean();
                //send the email
                $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
                //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
                //echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
                if($mail_sent === True)
                {
                    //echo "Mail Sent";
                }
                else{
                    //echo "Mail Failed";
                }
```